# Troubles with Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, event-handling

I have the following code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Window window = new Window("This is a title", 450, 350);
        JButton buttonExit = new Button("Exit", 75, 25);
        window.addElement(buttonExit);
        window.build();
    }
}

class Window // extend the current class
{
    public Window window;
    public JFrame frame;
    public JPanel panel;
    public String title;

    // instantiate object with the constructor
    public Window(String title, int width, int height)
    {
        this.frame = new JFrame(title);
        this.frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        this.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // centers the main window relative to the center of the screen dimension
        this.panel = new JPanel();
        this.panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        //this.panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.frame.add(panel);
    }

    public void build()
    {
        this.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.frame.pack(); // removes all unnecessary pixel space from the form
        this.frame.setVisible(true);
        this.frame.setSize(frame.getPreferredSize());
    }

    public void addElement(JButton element)
    {
        this.panel.add(element);
    }
}

class Button extends JButton // extend the current class
{
    public Button(String text, int width, int height)
    {
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        button.setText(text);
        button.setVisible(true);
        new ButtonHandler(button);
    }
}

class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public ButtonHandler(JButton button)
    {
        button.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

I have two problems with this:

1. The button is compressed and won't show its text
2. I cannot get the event handler to work and don't appear to get why

As a side note, I know that I don't specify a LayoutManager here, but I had this implemented before and it didn't solve my issue (I tried the FlowLayoutManager and the GridBagLayout [this would be my desired one, due to its flexibility]).

Can someone tell me, what I am doing wrong here? I've only worked with C# and WPF/WinForms before...

Comment: *"I have two problems with this:"* You may have two, but the code is littered with problems.  1) Swing & AWT GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT. 2) `class Window // extend the current class` No it doesn't, it extends `Object` (by default) but nothing else. However it does contain *an attribute* that is a `Window` .. then never uses it. Further, it should not be be called `Window` which risks using `java.awt.Window` instead. The constructor makes it more specific, but it's still confusing to people trying to help debug or maintain the code later. ..

Comment: .. 3)  See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) 4) `setLocationRelativeTo(null);` better to use `setLocationByPlatform(true)` 5) `this.frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height)); ..  this.panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));` The frame has borders and a title bar, so the frame and its content cannot be the same size. Further, the isze needed for the inner panel is no better than a guess. Use layout managers, borders and padding and let the JRE figure out best size. ..

Comment: .. 6) `this.panel = new JPanel();` This gets a `FlowLayout` by default, so the 'aside' below is erroneous. 7) `this.frame.setSize(frame.getPreferredSize());` Given it was just packed, that would be redundant, but it's handy to instead call `this.frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getPreferredSize());` 8) `class Button extends JButton` Now that **does** extend `JButton`, but .. don't do that. Most of what is done in the constructor is counter-productive, the rest is better handled with a factory method, and again the name clash. 9) `new ButtonHandler(button);` this creates then immediately ignores ..

Comment: Many of these things were relics of my testing and I agree, I should have removed them. Your first point was very helpful in clarifying why the event handler didn't work

Comment: .. or discards the handler. It needs to be added to a component to have an effect. 10)  `JButton button = new JButton(); .. button.setText(text);` better written as `JButton button = new JButton(text);` 11) .. I could go on, but won't. It'd take more characters to catalog the problems with that code, than are **in** the code itself. Toss it out, do the [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) in the tutorial and start again.

Answer (score 1):

### Issue 1:

Your custom `Button` class is-a `JButton` but also has-a `JButton` (named `button`) in the constructor.
The problem here is you install the `ButtonHandler` class to the `button` of the constructor, not the custom `Button` itself (which is referred to as `this` inside the constructor).

### Issue 2:

When you set the [preferred] size of the `JFrame` property named `frame` (in the custom class named `Window`), you are not setting the frame's contents' [preferred] size, but the size of the whole `JFrame`, which includes the bar located at the top of the frame (which has the title of the frame).
That lets the contents of the frame to have a space less than the preferred size, because the preferred size is set to the whole frame.
I know, you are also setting the preferred size of the `JPanel` named `panel`, which is added to the frame, but when you `pack` the frame, then the preferred size of the frame is prioritized rather than the preferred size of the contents of the frame, so that's probably why you are seeing the button compressed.

Let me demonstrate what I mean, with a bit of code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestFramePrefSz {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing JFrame preferred size");
            final JPanel contents = new JPanel();
            contents.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
            frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(contents);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println(contents.getSize());
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, the dimension object printed (which is the actual size of the panel) is about 184x161 rather than 200x200 requested, because the preferred size of the frame is also set to 200x200 (which includes the title of the frame etc...).

The solution, is to only set the preferred size of the contents, not the frame (in this particular scenario at least).

So you should:

1. Remove the line `this.frame.setSize(frame.getPreferredSize());` inside the `build` method.
2. Remove the line `this.frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));` inside the constructor of the custom class named `Window`.

### Issue 3:

The line `this.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` inside the constructor of the custom class named `Window`, is not effective in that place.
Imagine that, when you call this method, it has to determine the location of the frame to set it.
So it needs to know first of the size of the screen and then the size of the frame itself.
But what is the size of the frame at the point where you call this method? It is about 0x0. Not the preferred size as you might expect.
That makes the calculation of the frame's location to be such that the frame will not be centered at the screen.
That's because the preferred size is a property of the frame, which is a different property than the size.
So you either have to `setSize` prior making the call, or better to set the preferred size of the contents of the frame (ie `this.panel`), then call `pack` on the frame and finally call the method `this.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null)`.
Then you are free to set the frame to visible to see where it is located in the screen (ie should be centered).

So the solution is to follow a pattern like the following:

1. Create the frame, add the contents of the frame to it and set the contents' preferred size.
2. Call `pack` on the frame (remember this call will change the size of the frame, according to the preferred sizes of the contents of the frame or the frame's itself).
3. Call `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` on the frame.
4. Call `setVisible(true)` on the frame.

If you take a look at your code, you are instead doing:

1. Create the frame.
2. Set the preferred size of the frame.
3. Call `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` on the frame (but the size of the frame is not set yet).
4. Add the contents of the frame to it (ie the `panel`).
5. Call `addElement` which adds more content to the `panel`.
6. Call `pack` on the frame (remember the preferred size of the frame is set up to this point, so it will override any other preferred sizes, such as the contents' preferred size).
7. Call `setVisible(true)` on the frame.
8. Call `setSize` on the frame, with the preferred size of it. So you are overwriting the size the frame has had from step 6.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're using as a tutorial.  I recommend the Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  You can skip the Netbeans section, but I recommend going through the rest of the sections.

I created the following GUI.

[image: JButton Example GUI]

The Exit button works, disposing of the GUI.  The X in the upper right also disposes of the GUI.

Here's the runnable example code.  The explanation follows the code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JButtonExample implements Runnable{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JButtonExample());
    }

    private JFrame frame;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("This is a title");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                exitProcedure();
            }
        });

        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(
                75, 100, 75, 100));

        JButton button = new JButton("Exit");
        button.addActionListener(new ExitListener(this));
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return panel;
    }

    public void exitProcedure() {
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public class ExitListener implements ActionListener {

        private JButtonExample example;

        public ExitListener(JButtonExample example) {
            this.example = example;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            example.exitProcedure();
        }

    }

}
```

1. I make a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method from the `main` method.  This method makes sure that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
2. I separate the `JFrame` code from the `JPanel` code.  This is so I can focus on one part of the GUI at a time.
3. The `JFrame` methods have to be called in a specific order.  This is the order that I use for most of my Swing applications.
4. The `WindowListener` (`WindowAdapter`) gives my code control over the closing of the JFrame.  This will allow the Exit button `actionListener` to close the `JFrame`.  A `WindowListener` is not a simple concept.
5. The `JFrame` `defaultCloseOperation` is usually set to EXIT_ON_CLOSE.  In order for the `WindowListener` to work, I had to set the `defaultCloseOperation` to DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE.
6. I let the `JFrame` determine its own size by using the `pack` method.
7. I set the preferred size of the `JPanel`.
8. I created an empty border for the `JPanel`, so the `JButton` would expand to fill the rest of the `JPanel`.  That's what happens to the component placed in the center of a BorderLayout.
9. I created an `ExitListener` class.  Because it's an inner class, I didn't have to create a constructor or pass the `JButtonExample` instance.  I created a constructor so you can see how it's done, and how the `actionListener` method can execute the `exitProcedure` method of the `JButtonExample` class.

I hope this JButton example is helpful.  The WindowListener is a bit advanced for a simple example, but you can see how it's done.